# Why isn't my password complexity regex accepting my value?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I have given Regular Expression for Password Property as

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%.]).{8,16})*$", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain atleast one digit and one speacial character")]
public string Password{get; set;}
```

I have given password as `bobby@15`. I am not able to register. Is there any problem with Regular expression

Comment: I've tried to update your title to better explain your issue - feel free to amend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to escape `\d`.

```
@"^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%.]).{8,16})*$"
```